# Les « œufs du bétail » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, noms, france

De toujours, ce que l'on appelle le bétail n'a jamais été compris comme étant une source d'œufs. Les définitions des dictionnaires, assez récents ou mis à jour en permanence confirment ce fait.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A9tail)) A.− Ensemble des animaux élevés dans telle ferme, à l'exception des animaux de basse-cour.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A9tail)) Ensemble des animaux domestiques d’une exploitation rurale, en exceptant la volaille.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%A9tail/8932)) Nom désignant les animaux concourant à la production agricole, la volaille exceptée. (Le gros bétail se compose du cheval, de l'âne, du mulet et des bovinés ; le mouton, la chèvre, le porc forment le menu bétail [ou petit bétail].)

Même la [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9tail), qui est régulièrement mise à jour, confirme qu'il n'y a pas de changement dans la signification de ce nom.

> Le bétail (terme collectif, sans pluriel) est l'ensemble des animaux d'élevage, excepté celles de basse-cour et d'aquaculture. [excépté « ceux de »]

Cependant, dans un [article récent](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/voyage/actualite/cannibalisme-et-massacres-la-sombre-histoire-de-la-piste-de-l-oregon/ss-AA17SIv7?ocid=msedgntp&cvid=216980313247476c9b1ec8145cfde785&ei=78#image=11) on trouve la phrase suivante.

- Le lait, les œufs et le lard étaient fournis par le bétail.

J'ai la question la suivante ; est-ce que récemment le mot bétail aurait commencé à être  utilisé différemment pour inclure tous les animaux de ferme ? Sinon, est-ce que  seraient tolérable des approximations telles que celle-ci, qui assimile la volaille au bétail ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'article en question provient de pages qui ont été traduites automatiquement par un programme, très probablement DeepL. On y trouve donc pas mal d'expressions peu ou pas idiomatiques et calques de l'anglais.

Voici l'[original](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/travel/news/cannibalism-and-massacres-the-dark-history-of-the-oregon-trail/ss-AA17Q8iI#image=11) :

> Common foods migrants brought along included flour, sugar, rice, lard, dried fruit, and coffee. Pioneers would then hunt and fish along the trail. Milk, eggs, and bacon was supplied by **livestock**. This required careful planning, as when not accounted for, delays or other issues along the way could lead to malnutrition and even starvation.

Ce "**bétail**" correspond donc à ***livestock*** or il se trouve que ***livestock*** exclut la volaille. On ne peut donc pas reprocher à la traduction d'être fausse puisqu'elle ne fait que propager l'erreur originale. Elle aurait certes pu la corriger, mais il ne faut pas en demander trop à un programme.

*Est-ce qu'une approximation comme celle-ci est tolérable ?*

Je dirais oui, j'y ai survécu sans dommages.